# Getting FullContent from blobBaseClient.DownloadToAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download blob using [BlockBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) [DownloadToAsync](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.7.0/api/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.html#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DownloadToAsync_System_String_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_Azure_Storage_StorageTransferOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method.
As mentioned in documentation, I provided required param, but getting only partial content.
Related code is:

```
            string messageJson = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var blobBaseClient = new BlobBaseClient(_connectionString, _containerName, blobName);
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                CancellationToken cancelToken = new CancellationToken();
                StorageTransferOptions storageTransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
                {
                    //bytes * 1000000 = MB
                    InitialTransferSize = blobInitialChunkSize.Value * 1000000,
                    MaximumConcurrency = blobChunkUploadMaxThreadCount.Value,
                    MaximumTransferSize = long.MaxValue
                };

                BlobRequestConditions blobRequestConditions = new BlobRequestConditions();
                Response response = await blobBaseClient.DownloadToAsync(stream, blobRequestConditions, storageTransferOptions, cancelToken);
                if(response.Status == Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        messageJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("response.Headers.ContentType : " + response.Headers.ContentType + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("response.Headers.ContentLength : " + response.Headers.ContentLength + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("response.Headers.ETag : " + response.Headers.ETag + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("response.Headers.RequestId : " + response.Headers.RequestId + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("response.Status : " + response.Status + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("response.ReasonPhrase : " + response.ReasonPhrase + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation("stream : " + stream + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.Message + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.StackTrace + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.Source + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.InnerException + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        return messageJson;
```

the result I got is else block(not exception) & log values :

```
response.Headers.ContentType : application / octet - stream
response.Headers.ContentLength : 189778220
response.Headers.ETag : 0x8D860678531E07B
response.Status : 206
response.ReasonPhrase : Partial Content
stream: System.IO.MemoryStream
messageJson:
```

I want to know how can I get full data instead of Partial Data ? Any pointers/Help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried without specifying any options in DownloadToAsync()? I never used them so far and it always worked. So remove StorageTransferOptions and BlobRequestConditions

Comment: I am trying to use `StorageTransferOptions `InitialTransferSize` & `MaximumConcurrency` for chunking data greater than 100 MB only & max threads not more than 10

Comment: ok but I'm asking if you have tried to remove those to see if then you get the full content?

Comment: Let me try after removing

Comment: @silent still same after removing all param except stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on [Bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/17945) I asked on Github, I have added success condition for HTTP 206 too and it is working fine:

```
            if ((response.Status == Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                || response.Status == Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent))
            {
                using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.ContentStream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                messageJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the code bellow with `DownloadAsync` method, it will return 200.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
{
    var response = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Value.Content))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Azure Blob storage supports return 206 response if you're using API version 2011-01-18 or later. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob#status-code) says:

> A successful operation to read the full blob returns status code 200
> (OK).
>
> A successful operation to read a specified range returns status code
> 206 (Partial Content).

Comment: DownloadToAsync operation downloads a blob using parallel requests for large blobs, I intent to replace DownloadAsync which is already working for me too

Comment: Upvoted it, found this to be helpful after few hours of struggle. And have shared my code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388123/how-to-stream-binary-file-from-the-blob-storage-through-azure-function/73007182#73007182