# How to speed up file download on site hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a customer business app that I wrote for a client.  It is a Customer Tracking app, and involves uploading and download customer related files.

The files are kept in SQL Server.  For small files say smaller than a meg, it works fine.  But when the files get larger, then the time it takes to download the files becomes slower and slower until an exception is thrown.  Sometimes a large 25 meg will download, but other times, it will time out.

Today, the client cannot download 5 meg files as it times out after about 60 seconds.

When I run the app from my Dev Machine to the same database, the file downloads in about 10 seconds.  So it seems to me the issue is not the database, but the AppService hosting.

When I look at the logs of the AppService on Azure, it shows the CPU maxing out when these files are downloaded.

The site is currently on an S1 plan at $75 and the next plan up is $150 per month which seems mighty costly for a low use site.  It's only used by 3-4 people.  The speed is great other than with these large file downloads.

The code is fairly simple:

```
var file = await this._attachmentRepository.GetFileAsync(id);

FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(file.Content, file.ContentType)
{
    FileDownloadName = file.FileName
};
return result;
```

Any suggestions on how to optimize this?

Comment: Have you considered storing the files in blob storage instead of database (just store the blob URL in the database)? That would be the recommended approach.

Comment: @GauravMantri, That seems like a good idea, will look more into this.

Comment: Note that the added advantage of moving content to blobs is that you can provide a reference link and have the downloads happen without any intermediary (such as your web app) providing the streaming (eliminating a throttle point and reducing load on your app service). I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468172/272109) that talks more about this (yes it's nearly 6 years old but the answer is still valid, aside from the SDK code itself, since the SDK has evolved over the years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what that attachment repository is, but it's pretty obvious you're loading the entire file in memory before sending it back as an action result. The amount of memory copying alone, not counting the GC pressure and I/O, should give you a hint that this is absolutely the wrong thing to do.

What you want to do instead is open a `Stream` to your file, then return a `FileStreamResult` which will copy the data straight to the client as it becomes available from I/O without allocating gigantic amounts of memory on the server.

Comment: The files are currently stored in the database, and Azure does not support the FileStream datatype.  So unfortunately, I cannot use FileStreamResult without changing the way the files are stored.  But you are correct that the file is getting read into memory first which is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't believe any database that lets you load entire files into it (ie any modern database) doesn't have a streaming mechanism. In fact a quick google search found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/streaming-blobs-to-and-from-sql-azure/), with this quote near the top: `Create a console application to copy a file of BLOB data to SQL Azure from the command line without having to load the whole BLOB into memory.`

Comment: Also one from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388123/how-to-stream-binary-file-from-the-blob-storage-through-azure-function. Note the `FileStreamResult` usage.

Comment: I think you are correct!  I am going to check that out more

Comment: See this follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576072/how-to-return-filestreamresult-with-sqldatareader