# How to return FileStreamResult with SqlDataReader

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project that downloads large files which are stored in SQL Server. It works fine for small files, but large files often time out as they are read into memory before getting downloaded.

So I am working to improve that.

Based on [SQL Client streaming support examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) I have updated the code to the following:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFileAsync(int id)
{
     ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
     var file = await this._attachmentRepository.GetFileAsync(id);

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
     {
         await connection.OpenAsync();

         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Content] FROM [Attachments] WHERE [AttachmentId] = @id", connection))
        {
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", file.AttachmentId);
             SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

             if (await reader.ReadAsync())
             {
                 if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
                 {
                     Stream stream = reader.GetStream(0);
                     var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, file.ContentType)
                     {
                         FileDownloadName = file.FileName
                     };

                     return result;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return null;   
 }
```

But when I test, it throws this exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SqlSequentialStream'

Is there a way to fix this exception?

Comment: Test  removing the `using` since it may be disposing the stream before the request is done with the it

Comment: I tested, and I think that was the issue.  I am going to test some more to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `using` statements are all triggering when you do your `return`, thus disposing your connection and command, but the whole point of this is to leave the stream copy to happen in the background *after* your function is done.

For this pattern you're going to have to remove the `using` calls and let garbage collection trigger when the stream copy is done. `FileStreamResult` should at the very least call `Dispose` on the stream you give it, which should un-root the command and connection to be later finalized and closed.

Comment: I'm looking to use this code (without the usings), but I it never disposes the connection and our connection pool eventually maxes out.

Comment: Use a memory profiler and see what's keeping it rooted then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to close your connections, or wrap them in a using and it will do it for you. I reduced my code to just creating a new connection and opening it, and it leaks.

Comment: Are you not aware of finalizers, or how they work? There's an entire fleet of mechanisms built into the connection pool to reclaim non-disposed connections. What you call leak is simply how the .Net memory model works.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with finalizers. This is an MVC controller and the connection is scoped at a method level, so I can't utilize a finalizer to dispose of that. I've been working with databases across multiple large corporations for 30+ years and we've always had to explicitly close/dispose our connections (and file handles and streams). GC is reliable for everything else. Simple matter of fact is, that with this code, the app pool maxes out pretty quickly. And as I said, reducing my code to just creating and opening a new connection (and not doing anything with it) is leaking.

Comment: Some more info, I'm using this code to serve an image gallery, and it can request over 100 images in under 1 minute, which maxes out the app pool. The GC and/or connection pool clean up mechanisms may kick in at some later point, but until it does, the app can't get another connection from the pool. So this doesn't scale.

Comment: Feel free to post a better answer if you have it. I'd also say feel free to post a question about finalizers if you need help understanding them (nobody said you need to write one, it's already written for you in the sql connection class) -- but you seem like the guy who invents a mechanic and sticks with it rather than find out how things actually work.

Comment: I came here seeking help, but you are coming across as pretty hostile. I just hope that anyone that comes across this post in the future knows that this code can max out the app pool and leave your application dead in the water.

Comment: If this is your way of actually asking for help (it really doesn't sound like it), then the answer is very simple: if you're running out of connections then they're being kept open by active requests -- especially if you're doing something crazy like open HTTP connections. If this is the case, copy the data to either memory or physical files and return a stream to those instead, thus allowing you to close the Sql connection right away.

Comment: "this code can max out the app pool and leave your application dead in the water" -- this code does exactly what it says. It's up to you to figure out how to deal with problems that arise from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code, which is dramatically faster than without the streaming:

```
[HttpGet("download")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFileAsync(int id)
{

    var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    var fileInfo = await this._attachmentRepository.GetAttachmentInfoByIdAsync(id);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Content] FROM [Attachments] WHERE [AttachmentId]=@id", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", fileInfo.Id);

    // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
    // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
    SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
                
    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
        {
            Stream stream = reader.GetStream(0);        
            var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, fileInfo.ContentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileInfo.FileName
            };
            return result;  
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```