# ASP.NET Core Web API : async file download leaking SQL connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project returning images from SQL Server to an Angular app in a web browser. Images in SQL Server are stored using a SQL filestream. I don't want to load the entire image into memory, but instead want to return a `FileStream` result.

The following code works, but this code doesn't close the `SqlConnection` and after awhile the connection pool maxes out. Any help on making sure the `SqlConnection` gets closed?

**UPDATE**: just found this researching this problem, and this must be where I grabbed this code from in the first place: [How to return FileStreamResult with SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576072/how-to-return-filestreamresult-with-sqldatareader)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string context, ImageSizes size)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var imageId = _contextService.ContextToId(context);

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ImageContent_Select", sqlConnection);

    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageId", imageId));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageSize", size.ToString()));

    // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
    // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
    SqlDataReader reader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
        {
            Stream stream = reader.GetStream(0);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If I add using to my statements, as suggested in the comments below...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string context, ImageSizes size)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var imageId = _contextService.ContextToId(context);

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ImageContent_Select", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageId", imageId));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageSize", size.ToString()));

            // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
            // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
            using (var reader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
                    {
                        using (var stream = reader.GetStream(0))
                        {
                            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SqlSequentialStream'.
>
> at System.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StreamCopyOperationInternal.CopyToAsync(Stream source, Stream destination, Nullable`1 count, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Internal.FileResultHelper.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileResultExecutorBase.WriteFileAsync(HttpContext context, Stream fileStream, RangeItemHeaderValue range, Int64 rangeLength)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileStreamResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileStreamResult result)

Comment: One thing I'm not seeing here is using `using` with your resources (connections, filestreams). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using

Comment: If I add a "using" (as I typically do) it breaks the function because it's using CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess and reader.ReadAsync, this allows the file to be streamed in chunks to the browser, without bringing the entire image into memory on the server.

Comment: @DavidHoffman Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which uses `using` blocks and fails/breaks in your code (specially with `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`).

Comment: Hmmm... the code posted does include the reproducible example of my problem, it leaks Sql connections. If I add using blocks it throws an error: "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SqlSequentialStream'". That's because the using block will close the connection at the end of the function and before the async task has completed streaming the file, because the task is still running after the function completes.

Comment: It means, edit your question so it will contains the using, so we'll be able to address the relavant issue

Comment: Ok, question now includes code modified to having using statements, and the resulting error. To be clear, my original code does not error, but leaks Sql connections.

Comment: Try `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunately adding CommandBehavior.CloseConnection didn't work. I'm still leaking connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and implement the `Stream` (as well as its all method - just call base.(something))

```
public class CustomStreamWrapper : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly Action _onDispose;

    public CustomStreamWrapper(Stream stream, Action onDispose)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _onDispose = onDispose;
    }

    protected override void Dispose()
    {
        _onDispose.Invoke();

        //rest
    }
}
```

Usage will be something like:

```
var customStream = new CustomStreamWrapper(stream,()=>{ 
sqlConnection.Dispose(); });
 return new FileStreamResult(customStream, ...);
```

UPDATE:

> but unfortunately without wrapping the stream in a using statement
> Dispose() is never called. And if I wrap the stream in a using
> statement then I get the error: "System.NotSupportedException: Stream
> does not support reading." So it's back to the same problem, that
> adding a using anywhere in this code breaks it.

So you should seperate the stream from the connection (so it will be safe to dispose), I don't know how it should be impact on performance:

Its better to keep it somewhere else than the controller,
and let FileStreamResult handle the dispose:

```
using (var dbStream = reader.GetStream(0)) 
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await dbStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream; 
}
```

The controller should like clean:

```
var stream = await _service.GetImageStreamAsync(context, size);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, ...);
```

Comment: This is an API being called from an Angular app. Either way, adding an await would break the need for this to be async, I don't want to bring the entire image into memory on the server, just stream chunks of it at a time from the database to the web browser.

Comment: Oh, that make it more intresting, stay tuned

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not being specific about that. Just updated the question to include that info.

Comment: That's clever thinking. I gave it a try, but unfortunately without wrapping the stream in a using statement Dispose() is never called. And if I wrap the stream in a using statement then I get the error: "System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading." So it's back to the same problem, that adding a using anywhere in this code breaks it.

Comment: Per your last comment above, doesn't introducing the await load the entire file stream into memory?

Comment: Using an intermediate `MemoryStream` will indeed copy the whole thing in memory, which is definitely not good if your files are large enough.

Comment: If the files are to big you should be using a different approach, like a blob storage or maybe copying them from db to a temp folder on server

Comment: It's not they the images are overly large, but we have to be concerned with scalability and chewing up all the memory on the server. We chose Sql FileStream because it's supposed to deal with this nicely. Also can't do file system, because we need to authorize access to the files from the web browser client via the API and user auths.

Comment: Give the wrapping a try, not sure this is true: `without wrapping the stream in a using statement Dispose() is never called`, I think the `FileStreamResult` should handle it.